# Rubymine, Is there way of getting list of changed file compare to other branch? (or other commit of same branch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine, intellij-plugin

In ruby mine, there is a Local Change section, you can see the list of file that has been changed from your last commit.

[image]

but I want to see the list of files that has been changed **against another branch** or **another commit.** is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare branches https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manage-branches.html#compare_branches
Also, you can click RMB on the root of your project and choose "Git->Compare with" to compare with a commit or "Git->Compare with Branch...".
You can do the same with individual files.